# Why grep doesn't work on lists in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

In Perl,

```
my @lista = ['THE', 'KITE', 'RUNNER'];
my @listb = grep { $_ ne 'KITE' } @lista;
print "" . Data::Dumper->Dump(\@listb);
```

prints nothing while

```
my @lista = ('THE', 'KITE', 'RUNNER');
my @listb = grep { $_ ne 'KITE' } @lista;
print "" . Data::Dumper->Dump(\@listb);
```

prints an array containing 'THE' 'RUNNER'.

Why grep doesn't work when array is defined within `[]`?

How to do grep operations on an array defined in `[]`?

Comment: I don't see how it "_prints nothing_". Your `@lista` has one element which is an arrayref, as explained in ikegami's answer. That is duly not equal to `'KITE'` and so the condition in `grep` block is true, and that element passes. So `@listb` contains that one element, a reference that was assigned to `@lista`. This isn't what you want of course, but `print Dump(\@listb)` should print.

Answer (score 11):

`[]` doesn't return an array; it returns a reference to an array. A such, `@lista` only contains one element. You are comparing the stringification of that reference (something like `ARRAY(0x61dc18)`) with `KITE`. Seeing as those two strings are completely different, `grep` returns the reference and you store it in `@listb`.

I think you want the following:

```
my $array_a = ['THE', 'KITE', 'RUNNER'];
my @array_b = grep { $_ ne 'KITE' } @$array_a;
print Data::Dumper->Dump(\@array_b);
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` works on array, but `[]` returns an arrayref. To use an array, use `()` instead. 
 Here are two alternates to your program:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $lista = ['THE', 'KITE', 'RUNNER'];
my @listb = grep { $_ ne 'KITE' } @$lista;
print Dumper \@listb;
```

OR

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @lista = ('THE', 'KITE', 'RUNNER'); 
my @listb = grep { $_ ne 'KITE' } @lista;
print Dumper \@listb;
```